# How to set up a postfix dummy smtp server in Travis-CI for use with a Phoenix app?

Tags: email, smtp, travis-ci, apache-phoenix, postfix-mta

I am working on a Elixir/Phoenix app that uses [Bamboo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bamboo) to send email using a server at 127.0.0.1:25. My TravisCI builds fail because of the lack of a SMTP server in the TravisCI environment. How can I set up the travis-yaml to install a postfix server and set it up to disable outgoing mail? So far I have the following in my travis-yaml:

```
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -y -qq postfix
```

Which successfully installs postfix, but now I need to figure out how to start it and disable outgoing mail, which I am having trouble figuring out how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mailhog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) as a mock smtp server;

It provides SMTP server and UI. If you just want to send emails it'll be a great fit.

HOW TO:

```
before_install:
   - go get github.com/mailhog/MailHog
   - go install github.com/mailhog/MailHog
script:
   - sudo $GOPATH/bin/MailHog &>/dev/null &
```

then connect to localhost:1025 for sending emails.